# Android GCM push message On/Off handling

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented GCM in my application. Its working properly. I have a GCM switch On/Off in my app settings. When the user switched GCM to off, I am `fetching the registered ID` and `removing it from my third party server` and `adding again when switched to On`.

Is this implementation is correct or i need to un register and register every time when the user toggle the On/Off button?

Comment: Better way is that to store a flag into prefs.. and check on each message.

Comment: Instead of unregistered your device, its better to check whether GCM switch is on? then display message otherwise just garbage it.

Comment: @Chintan Rathod Its waste of internet data

Comment: @Pavandroid, then there is one option there, don't unregistered your device. Just make a web service which put "boolean" value to indicate, whether to send any data or not. And you are done. Whenever user want to receive, call web service and you are done.

Comment: @Chintan Rathod That's what am doing currently. Am asking whether this is correct procedure or not? If we don't un register, whenever there is an update in the registration ID in GCM server, it will request the device to get updated with the new Registration ID. If user don't want push notifications, what is the need of getting updated registration ID's from GCM server?

Comment: sorry for previous comment. I read but during 1 hr, was doing my stuff and forgot your actual contents. Yes. You are right then. You can follow that approach.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if the user turn notifications off, you shouldn't be sending them.

If you choose to receive the notification anyway in the device and dont show it, you will still be consuming the users trafic and battery.

Comment: In my case, i am removing the registration id from Server. So, server is not going to send the requests until and unless we add registration id again.